# Django Admin Form fields don't update when change form is saved

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

In the admin form for a model. Before I submit the form.

I want to edit/add a foreign key model field, using the Django admins popup change form.
When I submit, I would like the fields to update with the newly added data that was created/edited in that popup change form without having to refresh the page and losing the form data input already.

```py
class Button(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

[image]

```py
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Start here, slug will be created from name.")
    software = models.ForeignKey(Software, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

[image]

Popup window form:

[image]

Back in the form that's still open, nothing changes:

[image]

I know that the form can update if you're adding an object to the same field:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can't seem to find any help on this subject. Any suggestions or help would be great.

Maybe it can't be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the Class from the model and use it in models.ForeignKey().
For example:

```
from .models import Location

class Button(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You've specified a string `Location`, but it should be the class.

Comment: I'll try changing that. But I've never had an issue setting that as a string before.

Comment: Yeah, no difference. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Sorry, then I might have missunderstood your question. It would work if you reload, right?

Comment: Correct, it shows up in the form if I refresh the page after the popup is saved and closes.